# Form all possible pathways (list/dict) from dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, path, chain

I am trying to form all possible pathways using a dataframe. I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'from': ['b','c','d','e','f','g'], 'to': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b','c','e']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

sample dataframe
[image]

Now, I want to make all possible pathways/chain using these 2 columns.Output should look something like this:

1. e -> b -> a
2. f -> c -> a
3. g -> e -> b -> a

If  possible, then representing them with numbers like:

1. e -> b -> a  = 5,2,1
2. f -> c -> a = 6,3,1
3. g -> e -> b -> a = 7,5,2,1

Update: From field can contain duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way from `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx
 
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to')
[[*nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=x, target='a')][0] for x in list('efg')]
[['e', 'b', 'a'], ['f', 'c', 'a'], ['g', 'e', 'b', 'a']]
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the suggestion, I tried this solution but taking only the first element [0] misses out on some of the other possible paths for my data.

Comment: Thanks, by tweaking a bit this suggestion worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
# first of all let's make 'from' as index of df
df.set_index('from', inplace = True)

pth = []
def path(df, ch, res = []):
    if ch in df.index:
        path(df, df.loc[ch]['to'], res + [df.loc[ch]['to']])
    else:
        global pth
        pth = res
        return

import string    # we will use it below for get character  position in alphabet

for el in df.index:
    path(df,el,[el])
    print('->'.join(pth))

    # when you speak about indexes, looks you want to get the character index in alphabet
    # so here is my code
    print([string.ascii_lowercase.index(i)+1 for i in pth])
    print('') 

Out[1]:
b->a
[2, 1]

c->a
[3, 1]

d->a
[4, 1]

e->b->a
[5, 2, 1]

f->c->a
[6, 3, 1]

g->e->b->a
[7, 5, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your input! I guess this will not work in case of duplicate entries in my column 'From'. Please correct if am wrong! Thanks again!

Comment: you are right, it seems more or less complicated than solution above. in code above it use recursion, that doesn't take in account forks in paths that possible on any levels of deep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with a generator to form the paths, and then `string.ascii_lowercase` to store the results numerically:

```
data = {'from': ['b','c','d','e','f','g'], 'to': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b','c','e']}
d = list(zip(data['from'], data['to']))
def get_paths(n, c = []):
   if n is None:
      yield from [i for k, _ in d for i in get_paths(k)]
   elif (r:=[b for a, b in d if a == n]):
      yield from [i for k in r for i in get_paths(k, c+[n])]
   else:
      yield c+[n]

result = list(get_paths(None))
#[['b', 'a'], ['c', 'a'], ['d', 'a'], ['e', 'b', 'a'], ['f', 'c', 'a'], ['g', 'e', 'b', 'a']]
```

---

Then, to convert to integers:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as al
new_results = [[al.index(b)+1 for b in i] for i in result]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 2, 1], [6, 3, 1], [7, 5, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your suggestions. Below code worked for me:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(test,'From','To',create_using=nx.DiGraph())
all_paths = []
y = test['From'].unique()
for var in y:
 paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G,source = var ,target = 'XYZ')
 all_paths.extend(paths)
all_paths
```